# Function for uniroot that has two parameters that need to be run across a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a function thatI am trying to solve with uniroot. It works fine with fixed values. It works fine if i want to change one parameter by feeding it to lapply and applying a vector. But i cant get it to run when I feed it multiple vectors to run through.

Right now I am trying to get to work using either mapply() or map2()

THIS WORKS

```
fdr<-seq(0.01,0.1,0.001)

fstar <- function(k,x) (((1-1/sqrt(x+1)-1+1/sqrt(1+fo))/((x)+(k*to)))-1/(2*(x+1)^(3/2)))

f <- sapply(fdr, function(k) uniroot(fstar, c(0,10000),k=k)$root)
```

THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO

```
fdr<-seq(0.01,0.1,0.001)
foB<- seq(1.01,1.1,0.001)

fstar <- function(k,fo,x) (((1-1/sqrt(x+1)-1+1/sqrt(1+fo))/((x)+(k*to)))-1/(2*(x+1)^(3/2)))

f <- mapply(fdr,foB, function(k,fo) uniroot(fstar, c(0,10000),k=k,fo=fo)$root)
```

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'Bk' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I expect to get a vector to spit out - containing the root solutions to each element of both vectors together. So first output would be root solution for when fdr = 0.01 and foB = 1.01 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mapply` FUN is by default is the first argument. That seems to be the error it is giving. (There is a typo in your `fstar` as well.)

```
fdr<-seq(0.01,0.1,0.5)
foB<- seq(1.01,1.1,0.1)

fstar <- function(k,fo,x) (((1-1/sqrt(x+1)-1+1/sqrt(1+fo))/((x)+(k*fo)))-1/(2*(x+1)^(3/2)))

f <- mapply(function(k, fo) uniroot(fstar, interval = c(0,10000), 
    k=k, fo=fo)$root, fdr, foB)
```

In `f`, the first element `f[1]`, corresponds to the `fdr = 0.01` and `foB = 1.01`, and `f[2]` for the second elements in `fdr` and `foB` etc.